# Calling Oracle Stored proc with user define type array

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, types

I need to call a stored procedure in oracle. One of the parameters is a user defined type like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_PK AS OBJECT
(
  SOURCE_ID INTEGER,
  ACCT_SYSTEM VARCHAR2(255)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_PK_ARR AS TABLE OF MY_PK
/

PROCEDURE get_data(pk_in IN my_pk_arr, my_coursor OUT t_cursor)
IS 
 ...
END
```

I am trying to call it like so:

```
var    pk          my_pk_arr 
var    my_cursor   t_cursor
execute  myschema.mypackage.get_data (pk ,  :my_cursor);
```

I can't figure out how to create the array. Is this possible or I need to create some sort of table to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call it like this if you're calling it via a script. sqlplus doesn't support user defined arrays etc.

```
declare
  v_pk   my_pk_arr;
  v_cur  t_cursor;
begin

  v_pk := MY_PK_ARR(MY_PK(1, 'a'), MY_PK(2, 'b')); -- or build in a loop etc.
  get_data(v_pk, v_cur);

end;
/
```